# JavaScript Dictionary Editor

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript dictionary with constants like this:

```
var cons = {};
cons.tabs = {
  TAB_MIN_WIDTH: 38,
  TAB_MAX_WIDTH: 195,
  scrollBar: {
    FADE_DUR: 600,
    [...]
  },
  [...]
}
```

What do you think is the easiest way to expose this dictionary to visitors and let them change values?

In other words: I need an interface that let's me do operations that would read in the console as `data.tabs.TAB_MIN_WIDTH = xxx`

Comment: Two input elements, one taking the name and one the value?

Comment: How do I even get the name like data.tabs.TAB_MIN_WIDTH from the the posted code?!

Comment: Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cons.tabs)` to get an array of key-name strings or `for(var key in cons.tabs)` to have `key` loop over the key-name strings.

Comment: goog idea, but then I will lose the cons.tabs prefix and that will make it more complicated to write the value back again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the open source JSON editor: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/. I'll tell you why. I just wrote a JSON interface for work and it was a lot of effort. The JSON I was dealing with was constantly changing (you could add/delete objects, arrays and strings from it) - that kind of data-set is very difficult (I found) to manage properly. I would have used the JSON editor linked above but my client decided that he wanted something bespoke designed instead. YMMV.

Comment: The data the OP has is not JSON, but it could easily be converted to JSON.

Comment: Good point. I've been staring at JSON for too long :)